# Develop a settings page that will save locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, load, save

I need guidance on a concept that would make my project really nice.

I am making a page with some options for changing the background image, table border colors, textarea background colors, etc.  The user can choose these options and should be able to save them.

I cannot use a database to save these settings because it is a work computer system and they won't allow that, so I am thinking I can save the settings locally to a text file and just load it back in when somebody logs in to the page again (logins are done through htaccess).

I know there's more than one thing involved for this but I could use some help with a very simple version of how to do this (choose options, save changes, onload[display]).

Sorry if this is too much, I know how nice it will be if I can a simple concept working.

Thanks!
-Sorv

Comment: You generally don't have access to the filesystem on the clientside, but there are clientside DB's, localStorage and cookies that would seem more appropriate for this.

Comment: You can use cookies or localStorage on the users computer. The drawback of this is that the setting do not follow the user if they have multiple computers.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.
@adeneo We do have some local file access.  I know this becasue I did manage to save and load with php locally."

Comment: @jeff It is true that if they used another machine they would lose their settings, but everyone has their own desk and its not a big deal if they move.

Comment: here's an idea, i don't have a clue how to do it, but this may help somone with more knolage get an answer.  You could have the settings save in a notepad.css file, which has a preset name, and link the new page to the html, which comtains the settings.  The css doc would have to download localy when the user logs in.  I have no idea if this is possible, but I would love to see it!

Comment: What I was thinking is to save the settings to a .txt like you said, then load them with php and have all the css as variables in the html elements.  Is that way off or could it be a valid solution?

Comment: Ok guys we are making progress.  Here's my java function:
...
function setbg()
{
 document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/bg3.png)";
}

<body id="body" onload="setbg()">
...
Is it possible to load the filename of the image from a txt document using php and put it in the "url(imagename)" space?  If so this thing will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cookies. You can do this server side or client side.

**Javascript**

If you use jquery:

```
function setbgsetting(color){
    $.cookie("background", color);
}
function loadbg(color){
    var bg = $.cookie("background");
    if (bg)
        $('body').css("background-color", bg);
}
```

**PHP**

```
function setbgsettings($color){
    $_COOKIE["background"] = $color;
}

// as PHP code in style tags, or style css
if (isset($_COOKIE["background"]))
    echo "background-color: ". $_COOKIE["background"].";";
```

Alternatively, you could add session_start (); to the top of ever page, and replace COOKIE with SESSION.

Comment: as far as i know, this will only work if they use the same computer every time

Comment: Correct. And the same browser.

Comment: Yes, and that's ok, one person per desk using the same browser.  Is there a php alternative?  I can work with this, just curious.

Comment: <style> background: <?=( isset( $_COOKIE['background'] ) ) $_COOKIE['background']; ?> </style> And set $_COOKIE in the settings page

Comment: that $_COOKIE could store an array, yes?  There will be multiple settings for each page element (bgcolor/image, table border, textarea bg's and borders) so I'm wondering if ill need a cookie for each one or if they can all be stored in a single cookie.  Thanks for that great reply!

Comment: You would need to serialise the array, ie turn it into a string.